# Special process of squaring of a number

Tags: c, operating-system

I have a c program (Assignment) that reads a number from user input and performs a square operation on it. Squaring operation is done in the following way:

1. The program calls the fork()
2. In the child process, execv() is used to call executable named "square" with number as a command-line argument.
3. parents process waits till the child finishes.

Now the problem is we can't use pipe, write to a file to get the value of squared number. So I thought the best way would be to return the value of squared number and obtain it in the parent process with the help of WEXITSTATUS.
This works fine till the squared number is less than 255 (as WEXITSTATUS return lower 8 bits only)

So I am asking is there any other approach possible.

EDIT: Only these are allowed:

fork,
exec* family,
ato* family,
printf, sprintf,
malloc,
free,
wait/ waitpid,
sqrt,
exit

Comment: Can you fork multiple times?   If you can, there's an obvious solution.

Comment: Yes, multiple forks are allowed. How it will help?

Comment: Simple - 8 child processes each return a separate byte of information that makes up the square root result you seek.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, multiple forks are allowed. How it will help?

Since each process can only return at most 1 byte of information via WEXITSTAUS, fork 8 child processes to compute each individual byte of an 8-byte floating point value.  Assumes that `sizeof(double) == 8`

Each child process will invoke the execv function - passing both the square number it's expected to compute sqrt for in addition to an the child processes index number (0-7) as a second parameter.

Your child process only needs a small modification. Something like this.

```
int square = atoi(argv[1]);
int result_index = atoi(argv[2]);

double result = sqrt(square);  // compute the square root

// now treat the double as an array of 8 bytes.  Return the
// byte value of the index passed in as the second command line parameater
unsigned char* ptr =  (unsigned char*)(&result);
unsigned char value = ptr[result_index]; // value is what you want to return to the parent process
exit(value);  // or "return value" - whatever you are doing to set WEXITSTATUS
```

The parent process waits for all 8 child processes to complete and uses the index of each child process to reconstruct the `double` computed in each

```
double result = 0;  // this will contain the square root after all 8 processes have finished
unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)(&result);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    <wait for child[i] to finish>
    unsigned char value = <the WEXITSTATUS of the child process>
    ptr[i] = value;
}
```

When all 8 child processes have completed and the parent process has fetched the result byte from each (stuffing each back into an offset on a pointer to double), the square root of the original value will be captured in `result`

You can have each forked process run one at a time or in parallel.